# how to edit and create event in Fullcalendar with Django

Tags: django, fullcalendar

I am trying to use calendar features in my site with events model.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    limit = models.Q(app_label='crm', model='Household', id=10) | \
    models.Q(app_label='crm', model='Lead', id=13) | \
    models.Q(app_label='crm', model='Opportunity', id=14) | \
    models.Q(app_label='crm', model='Case', id=11)
        name = models.CharField(
    pgettext_lazy("Name of the Event", "Event"),
    max_length=64)
```

On my html I have . the events displayed fine. 
Now, to add or edit an event. I have this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '{{today|date:'%Y-%m-%d'}}',
            editable: true,
            header: {
                                left: 'prev,next today prevYear',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'nextYear month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.close_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ],
            firstDay:1,
              slotDuration:'00:15:00',
              scrollTime:'07:00:00',
              selectable: true,
              selectHelper: true,
              ignoreTimezone: false,
              lazyFetching:true,

            select: function(start, end) {
                     eventType="";
                     $("#eventDialogLabel").html("New Appointment");
                     $("#eventID").val('');
                     $('#eventDialog').modal('show');
                     startDate=start;
                     $("#deleteButton").hide();

              },

              eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                     eventType="";
                     $("#eventDialogLabel").html("Update Appointment");
                     $("#eventID").val(calEvent._id);
                     alert(calEvent._id);
                     $("#modal-body").html(calEvent.title);
                     $("#deleteButton").show();
                     $('#eventDialog').modal('show');
                     startDate=calEvent.start;
                     endDate=calEvent.end;


              },
              eventDragStart:function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
                     eventType="eventDragStart";
                     startDate=event.start
              },
              eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                     endDate=event.start;
                     EventDropOrResize(calEvent);
              },
              eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

                     EventDropOrResize(calEvent);

              },
        });

    });






$("#deleteButton").on('click',function(){



              doPOST('DELETE');
              return false;
       });
       function EventDropOrResize(calEvent)
       {
              $("#eventID").val(calEvent._id);
              alert(calEvent._id);
              endDate=event.start;
              startDate=event.end;
              appointmentType=event.allDay

              doPOST("PUT");
       }
       function doPOST(methodType)
       {

              $("#eventDialog").modal('hide');alert(calEvent);
              url="{% url 'riskengine:change_event' %}"
              if(calEvent !='')
              {alert(calEvent);
                     url+="?id="+$("#eventID").val();
              }
              var event={
            name_id: $("#id_title").val(),
            end:new Date(endDate),
            start:new Date(startDate),
                     type:$('#id_type').val(),
                     allDay:appointmentType
        }
              $.ajax({
                     type:methodType,
                     url:url,
                     datatype:'JSON',
                     data:JSON.stringify(event),


                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                     async: false,
                     success:function(data){
                           if(methodType=='DELETE')
                           {
                                  if($("#eventID").val()!='')
                                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', [$("#eventID").val()] );
                           }
                           else if(data.id)
                           {
                                  if(data.id == $("#eventID").val())
                                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', [data.id] );
                                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', {id:data.id , title: data.title,
                                  start:  event.start,end:  event.end}, false);
                           }
                           else
                                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
                     }
              });
              return false;
       }
```

My view to change the event

```
def change_event(request):
try:
    if request.is_ajax():
        id = request.GET.get('id')
        print(id)
        event = Event.objects.get(id=id)
        if request.method == "PUT":
            # used to edit/delete appointments
            json_data = request.read()
            data = json.loads(json_data)
            if id:
                # logic to edit an appointment
                return JsonResponse(
                    {'id': event.id, 'title': event.name, 'start': data['start_date'],
                     'end': data['end_date'],
                     'allDay': data['allDay']})
            return JsonResponse("")
        elif request.method == "GET":
            # used to get appointments
            events = None
            events = Event.objects.filter().order_by('start_date')
            return JsonResponse([{'id': o.id, 'title': o.name, 'start': (o.start_date.isoformat()),
                              'end': (o.end_date.isoformat()),
                              'allDay': IsFullDayAppointment(o.start_date, o.end_date)} for o in events])
        elif request.method == "POST":
            # used to save new appointments

            json_data = request.read()
            data = json.loads(json_data)
            event = Event.objects.create()
            event.save()
            return JsonResponse(
                {'id': event.id, 'title': event.name, 'start': data['start_date'], 'end': data['end_date'],
                 'allDay': data['allDay']})
        elif request.method == "DELETE":
        # used to delete appointments
            if id:
                print(id)
                Event.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
                return JsonResponse("",safe=False)

except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse(e,safe=False)
```

Try to get id from view and delete or edit. But I can't get event id back to the view. the json is 'undefined'. The calEvent._id is not responding. What is the right variable to get the event id?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to [refresh the model from the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database).

The `.save()` method doesn't re-load the data, which means you won't see the autogenerated id until you refresh the event.

Something like this should work:

```
event = Event.objects.create()
event.save()
event.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: that's not it. I am trying to get the event id from fullcalendar and pass it to the separated function doPOST('DELETE'). But the id in ($("#eventID").val() is 'undefined'.